Exploiting symmetry of 4d integral
In my research, I have come across the following integral in four variables.
$$I=32\int_0^\infty f(x,y,w,z) dx dy dz dw$$
The function $f$ is invariant under permutation of any of the variables and the integral boundaries are the same for each variable. $f$ itself depends on a complicated way on the variables but I am still hoping that I can leverage the symmetry properties to find an exact expression.
The function $f$ is given by
$$f(x,y,z,w)=\frac{(C_0(y,z,w)+C_1(y,z,w)x^2+C_2(y,z,w)x^4+C_3(y,z,w)x^6)^{1/2}}{(1+(xy)^2+(xz)^2+(xw)^2+(yz)^2+(yw)^2+(zw)^2+(xyzw)^2)^{5/2}}$$
where
$$C_0(y,z,w)=y^4z^2w^2+y^2z^4w^2+y^2z^2w^4+(yzw)^4$$
$$C_1(y,z,w)=w^6 y^4 z^4+w^6 y^2 z^2+w^4 y^6 z^4+w^4 y^4 z^6+w^4 y^2+w^4 z^2+w^2 y^6 z^2+w^2 y^4+w^2 y^2 z^6+w^2 z^4+y^4 z^2+y^2 z^4$$
$$C_2(y,z,w)=w^6 y^4 z^2+w^6 y^2 z^4+w^4 y^6 z^2+w^4 y^4+w^4 y^2 z^6+w^4 z^4+w^2 y^6 z^4+w^2 y^4 z^6+w^2 y^2+w^2 z^2+y^4 z^4+y^2 z^2$$
$$C_3(y,z,w)=w^4 y^4 z^2+w^4 y^2 z^4+w^2 y^4 z^4+w^2 y^2 z^2$$
Integrating numerically gives $I\approx 59.427$. I tried substitution of hyper-spherical coordinates but that didn't get me much further.
Suppressing the dependence on $y,z,w$ gives the integral over $x$ as
$$I_x=32\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{C_0+C_1x^2+C_2x^4+C_3x^6}}{(B_0+B_1x^2)^{5/2}}dx$$
which might be an easier problem to tackle.
Update:
After further investigation, I was able to derive that $I$ is equivalent to the case $k=4$ in the expression
$$J_k:=2^k \int_1^\infty d\vec{x}\left(\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{x_i}{x_i^2-1}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{x_i}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^k x_i\right)^{-(k+1)/2}$$
Where $J_1=\pi$, $J_2=\pi^2$, $J_3\approx 25.8589$, $J_4=I\approx 59.427$.
Update:
After more research and going down the rabbit hole of integer relation algorithms and tanh-sinh quadrature, I found that
$$J_3\approx 25.8589\approx e+e^\pi$$
Although I am very hesitant to claim that this is more than a coincidence, it would be a very interesting result.

Just a little thought : your expressions are non-homogeneous. Why not attempt to homogenize them by introducing - say - (at least) two new variables ?
